# How to predict/score XGBoost or LightGBM in .NET Framework 4.6.1 application

Tags: c#, xgboost, lightgbm, ml.net, onnx

I have a machine learning problem where I have obtained very good results on training/test data using both `LightGBM` and `XGBoost`. The next step is to obtain predictions from one of these models into an existing C# application (.NET Framework 4.6.1) Is there any library that can help me do this? What I have tried so far:

- [ML.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning): Should work for `LigthGBM`, but due to [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/494) it works only for .NET Core.
- [Windows.ML](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning): This should be able to predict an ONNX model, and I managed to create an ONNX model from my `XGBoost` model. But Windows.ML seems to work only for UWP apps, at least all samples are UWP.
- [SharpLearning](https://github.com/mdabros/SharpLearning): This library has an interface to `XGBoost`. Unfortunately, it does not support sample weights, which I rely upon.
- CNTK: Tried to load the ONNX file (similar to [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/release/latest/Examples/Evaluation/CNTKLibraryCSEvalCPUOnlyExamples)), but get: Error: ONNX (TreeEnsembleClassifier) is not supported in CNTK.

Any suggestions, or do I have to wait for ML.NET to fix the bug?

Comment: Since you have an ONNX model you may be able to use CNTK in C# to read and predict on it. I'll admit, it's not very trivial to do it though. This documtation may help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/using-cntk-with-csharp

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Jon. I tried this with my ONNX file, and when trying to load the file I get: Error: ONNX (TreeEnsembleClassifier) is not supported in CNTK. Have now added this to the "What I have tried so far" above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use LightGBM in a `net461` console application. The above bug only occurs if you are using `packages.config` to manage your NuGet packages. In order to work around the listed bug in the LightGBM nuget package, you can take one of the following approaches:

1. Use a new "SDK-style" .csproj, but set the TargetFramework to `net461`.

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.LightGBM" Version="0.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="iris-data.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

2. Change your normal .NET Framework .csproj to use `<PackageReference>` instead of `packages.config`. You can do this in the Package Manager Settings under Tools -> NuGet Package Manager menu.  "Default package management format". You can refer to the [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) document for more info.

```html
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML">
      <Version>0.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.LightGBM">
      <Version>0.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```